# Java - Issue retrieving value from hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a hashtable created:

`Hashtable next_hop = new Hashtable();`

I insert values like next_hop.put("R1","local") and so on...

The hashtable looks like this:

`{R5=R5, R4=R2, R3=R2, R2=R2, R1=Local}`

Now I try to retrieve the values from the keys as follows:

```
String endPoint = "R1";
for (Object o: next_hop.entrySet()) {
   Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) o;
   if(entry.getKey().equals(endPoint)){
       String nextHopInt = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

i get the following error:
error: incompatible types
                `String nextHopInt = entry.getValue();`

required: String

found:    Object

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `getValue()` returns an object, not a string, hence the error you are getting. You can cast the value by saying

```
String nextHopInt = (String) entry.getValue();
```

Comment: awesome...that works!

Comment: Also worth noting that `Hashtable` is very deprecated at this point and OP should be using `HashMap` instead. And to avoid this casting mess, it should be parameterized as `HashMap<String,String>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly cast the RHS if it is a downcast (Object -> String).

```
String nextHopInt = (String)entry.getValue();
```